# Formatting a ubuntu usb drive

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb

I have researched this on multiple occasions, and still have found nothing. So here is my problem, i installed ubuntu onto a 128gb flash drive. not live install the actual os, and chose the all encryption options. and now need to use the flash drive for something else but when plugged in it shows only 500mb free, even after i type in my password that i had used on it. After formatting some what free space that was available on it no longer works (booting up that is)any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Windows only sees the first partition on a flash drive.
In my experience formatting a multi partition flash drive in Windows can brick it.

As a minimum Gparted or Disks should be used to re-format the drive.

**Mkusb** is even better as it has a Wipe option and an option to reset the drive to it's original spec's with msdos partition table and FAT32 format.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe